# split string using java

Tags: java

I want to split a very long string that includes Date, time and some comments multiple time in same order,how to split these into date, time and comments separately using java.

Eg:

```
21 March 2012 3:48 PM 11 doz 30 September 2011 10:51 AM Hotlist Task Deleted: To-do Ring re: Boody (Jessica ordered socks)With: 3 Beaches Chemist Deleted by: MASTER 21 September 2011 12:55 PM Hotlist Task Created: To-do Ring re: Boody (Jessica ordered socks) With: 3 Beaches Chemist Scheduled by: MASTER Assigned to: MASTER 21 September 2011 12:55 PM 7 doz
```

I want output as:

```
Date              Time     Comments
21 March 2012     3:48 PM  11 doz
30 September 2011 10:51 AM Hotlist Task Deleted: To-do Ring re: Boody (Jessica ordered socks)With: 3 Beaches Chemist Deleted by: MASTER
21 September 2011 12:55 PM Hotlist Task Created: To-do Ring re: Boody (Jessica ordered socks) With: 3 Beaches Chemist Scheduled by: MASTER Assigned to: MASTER
21 September 2011 12:55 PM 7 doz
```

Comment: Please don't flag your question with "urgent" or "reply asap", please.

Comment: How do you know when a new entry starts when reading the input data? What if the comment includes a date?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a regular expression, but you have to have a line/entry delimiter between the entries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an algorithm that would look for value date strings per your know format (for example look for the next string that matches one of the months) and break the string based on that. Find the month, back up till you find the day and split.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using a regex expression to match the condition from where u want to break your string.

Also u can put a delimiter to let the regex expression know to break the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.replaceAll ("([0-3]?[0-9] [A-Z][a-z]+ 20[0-9][0-9] )", "\n$1")
```

Result:

```
21 March 2012 3:48 PM 11 doz 
30 September 2011 10:51 AM Hotlist Task Deleted: To-do Ring re: Boody (Jessica ordered socks)With: 3 Beaches Chemist Deleted by: MASTER 
21 September 2011 12:55 PM Hotlist Task Created: To-do Ring re: Boody (Jessica ordered socks) With: 3 Beaches Chemist Scheduled by: MASTER Assigned to: MASTER 
21 September 2011 12:55 PM 7 doz
```